# Search by array values in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase via REST API. I have following database structure:

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {},
    "Cat2" : {},
    "Cat3" : {},
    "Cat4" : {}
  },

  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "categories": ["Cat1", "Cat3"]
    },
    "item2" : {
      "categories": ["Cat1", "Cat3"]
    },
    "item3" : {
      "categories": ["Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3"]
    },
    "item4" : {
      "categories": ["Cat4"]
    }
  }
}
```

As you could see we have relations of type "N <-> N" between categories and items (one category could have several items and one item could be in several categories).

Now I want to get all items of Cat1 via Firebase REST API, but I can not do it.

As we know arrays are stored in the Firebase like map with integral indexes:

```
"categories": {
  "0": "Cat1",
  "1": "Cat2",
  "2": "Cat3",
}
```

So, I added `".indexOn": ["categories/*"]` to Realtime Database Rules and tried to call this:
`curl 'https://...firebaseio.com/...json?orderBy="categories/*"&equalTo="Cat1"'`

But I got only this: `{ }`

So, I think that regular expressions do not work in Firebase queries, because this worked:
`".indexOn": ["categories/0"]` in Realtime Database Rules and
`curl 'https://...firebaseio.com/...json?orderBy="categories/0"&equalTo="Cat1"'`

Of course, I could change the database model to something like this:

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {},
    "Cat2" : {},
    "Cat3" : {},
    "Cat4" : {}
  },

  "items" : {
    "item1" : {},
    "item2" : {},
    "item3" : {},
    "item4" : {}
  },

  "category-items": {
    "Cat1": ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
    "Cat2": ["item3"],
    "Cat3": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    "Cat4": ["item4"]
  }
}
```

And get the `category-items` and iterate through the `Cat1` array, but then I must to call REST API read method too many times (one REST API call for every `item` in the category). So, it is too expensive.

So, could anybody help me with getting all items in a category in origin database model?

**UPDATE**
The final model is:

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {},
    "Cat2" : {},
    "Cat3" : {},
    "Cat4" : {}
  },

  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item2" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item3" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat2": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item4" : {
      "Cat4": true
    }
  }
}
```

Also I added

```
{
  rules": {
    ...
    "items": {
      ".indexOn": [ "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4" ]
    }
  }
}
```

to Realtime Database Rules, and REST API call is
`curl 'https://...firebaseio.com/items.json?orderBy="Cat1"&equalTo=tr‌​ue'`

Thanks to Vladimir Gabrielyan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the structure which I would suggest to have.

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {
        "items": {
            "item1":{/*Some item info*/},
            "item2":{/*Some item info*/}
        }
    },
    "Cat2" : {
        "items": {
            "item3":{/*Some item info*/}
        }
    },
  },

  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "categories": {
          "Cat1": true,
      }
    },
    "item3" : {
      "categories": {
          "Cat2": true, 
          "Cat3": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside `Cat1/Items/{itemId`} and `items/{itemId}` you need to duplicate your `item` information, but I think that is okay.

Also see this article. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Thank you very much! Your suggestion with replace

```
"item1" : {
  "categories": ["Cat1", "Cat3"]
},
```

to

```
"item1" : {
  "Cat1": true,
  "Cat3": true
},
```

can solve the problem, but then I will have to add every `Cat` to `.indexOn` in Realtime Database Rules, but this is not so big problem as origin problem.

But I think that

```
"categories" : {
  "Cat1" : {
    "items": {
        "item1":{/*Some item info*/},
        "item2":{/*Some item info*/}
    }
  },
  "Cat2" : {
    "items": {
        "item3":{/*Some item info*/}
    }
  },
}
```

is not a good idea in my case because then we get many spare data every time we get information about `Cat` (when we no need list of items, only metadata of `Cat`). So, I suggest following model:

```
{
  "categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {},
    "Cat2" : {},
    "Cat3" : {},
    "Cat4" : {}
  },

  "items" : {
    "item1" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item2" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item3" : {
      "Cat1": true,
      "Cat2": true,
      "Cat3": true,
    },
    "item4" : {
      "Cat4": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: okay if you do not need to duplicate items inside `categories` I would suggest the same schema for categories.

`"categories" : {
    "Cat1" : {"items": {"item1":true,"Item2": true}}
  }`

In that case you can get all items for `cat1` with one request, and there would no need to store index on `items/{itemId}/cat1` in order to query all items for `cat1`

Comment: In that case I must to get full information about every `item` in separated REST API call. And this is too expensive in compare one REST API call to get all items of one category.

P.S.  
Every `Cat` and every `item` have some extra fields. The shown data model is just simplified model.

Comment: okay in that case there are two options. 1. duplicate all item data or 2. go with the way that you described below, just I guess you need add index something like this

`"items": {
    "$itemId": {
      "$category": {".indexOn": ".value"}
    }
  }`

Comment: Yes, you are right, in my case I added `"rules": { "items": { ".indexOn": [ "Cat1", "Cat2", "Cat3", "Cat4" ] } }` to Realtime Database Rules, because I use `orderBy` instead of `orderByValue`. And REST API call is `curl 'https://...firebaseio.com/...json?orderBy="Cat1"&equalTo=true'`