# NoSQL 'like' model structure

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I've had some relational database experience, but I am quite new to NoSQL databases. I am trying to do the following (in Firebase Firestore) I have a collection of user documents and a collection of item documents.
A user has to be able to Like an item. My relational database thinking mind shifts towards a structure where the ID of the user document and the ID of the item are saved in a table, but this wouldn't work in a NoSQL Database.

Without going into the details of the none working solution I came up, I was wondering if anyone here has a solution? I want to be able to get all liked items for a specific user without 100s of round trips to the server.

Edit @Jesús Fuentes: multiple users should be able to like the same item

Comment: Can't you just add a field in the item's document where you store the user IDs that like that actual item? Edit, this should give you the good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126811/how-do-you-track-record-relations-in-nosql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285295/search-by-array-values-in-firebase?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have a user document in your `users` collection, `user1`. `user1` sees an item that he likes, so he "likes" that item. In the `user1` document, a new collection is made, `likedItems`. In this user's `likedItems` collection, a document is added with the ID of the liked item, for example, `0001`.

Now if you want to get all liked items for a specific user, you just have to grab all documents from their `likedItems` collection.

The concept is the same for any language, but here's a JavaScript example:

```
db.collection(`users/${userId}/likedItems`).get().then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    // doc is the document for a liked item
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely use this method (Don't have enough reputation to upvote...)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually thanks to the help of @[Geoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9672799/geoff) and @[Egghead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853734/egghead) I managed to do it as followed:
Every Item has a Likedby Array with key:bool pairs, where the key is the userID and the bool is set to `true` if the user liked the item (adding all the other users with false isn't necessary). According to [The Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays)  this is the needed, because an array of just the strings of userID's can't be queried. 
example:

```
{
item: "Stackoverflow",
likedBy: {
    "Egghead": true,
    "Geoff": true,
    "f5172c0d83892c41b60de3f1fadd89": true
}
```

This can then be query using (Swift, see docs for other languages):

```
db.collection("posts")
             .whereField("likedBy.Egghead", isEqualTo: true)
                         .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in

    // do what you have to do

}
```

Comment: This solution is also good when you list products that are both liked and notLiked together. So you can check and show a "hearth" if item likedBy current user.